# how to get delphi TPaintBox handle

Tags: delphi, winapi, handle

im working on an application using **delphi 6**, where im trying to integrate camera into the existing application, the camera code displays the captured frames onto a Tpanel, in my application i need to display the captured frame on Tpaintbox ( i am not the original coder),

this is a code sample from the

```
  procedure TFrameThreadX.DrawFrame;
    var
    hdc:THandle; 
     begin
       
       //do processing
      .
      . 
       hdc := GetDC( ViewForm.ViewPanel.Handle );
       SetStretchBltMode(hdc,COLORONCOLOR);
       StretchDIBits(hdc,0,0,nW,nH,0,0,ScW,ScH,DibPixels,TBitMapInfo((@FDib)^),DIB_RGB_COLORS,SRCCOPY);
       ReleaseDC( ViewForm.ViewPanel.Handle, hdc );


     //do processing
    end;
```

here is get the Tpanel handle as **87248682** from this

```
  hdc := GetDC( ViewForm.ViewPanel.Handle );
```

so when i try to use Tpaintbox in the code like this

```
       hdc := GetDC( ViewForm.PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle);
```

The result is **0**,

so the camera frames are not displayed..

so i tried this

using the **GetDC** and **GetWindowDC** but in both the cases the result of the functions is **0** for the handle,

[image]

my code

```
   var
     hdc  : THandle;
     begin
       hdc := GetDC(Panel1.Handle);
       Label1.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
       hdc := GetDC(Image1.Canvas.Handle);
       Label2.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
       hdc := GetDC(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle);
       Label3.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
     end;
```

And for **GetWindowDC**

```
    var
     hdc  : THandle;
     begin
     hdc := GetWindowDC(Panel1.Handle);
     Label4.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
     hdc := GetWindowDC(Image1.Canvas.Handle);
     Label5.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
     hdc := GetWindowDC(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle);
     Label6.Caption:=inttostr(hdc);
    end;
```

So please tell me how to get the Tpaint handle?

Comment: You don't appear to be painting inside WM_PAINT

Comment: And THandle is the wrong type. You need HDC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Canvas.Handle is the DC handle you're looking for, so `HDC := PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle`

Comment: hey that worked, my Tpaintbox is capturing frames now, can you explain me what is the difference between `hdc := GetDC(PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle);` And `hdc := PaintBox1.Canvas.Handle`

Answer (score 4):

`TPaintBox` and `TImage` are `TGraphicControl` descendants and have no handle (they receive handle when they process WMPaint message). `TPanel` is `TWinControl` descendant and has a handle.